# Array copy loop makes every element the same

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I'm making a C program that should read a file and sort the strings that the file contains. To do that, I am trying to copy each string in the file into a `char*` array but have run into an issue. The following code ends up populating the whole array with the last string in the file and I'm at a loss as to what is going on. I've tested the loop and it does go through the file perfectly and it does copy each string into the array but each loop iteration makes every element in the array equal to `buff`.

```
// find the size of the file
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
long fileSize = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);

char* fileContents[fileSize]; // we're gonna copy the file into here
char buff[255];
long stringsInFile = 0L;
while( fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*) fp) ) {
    // copy the file into the array & get the number of strings
    fileContents[stringsInFile] = buff;
    stringsInFile++;
}
```

I'm sure it's something simple that I've overlooked; I feel silly not being able to copy strings into arrays.
This is absolutely homework, by the way!

Comment: you're not copying the data in `buff`, you're copying a pointer to the first character in `buff` (which doesn't change), over and over again, to `fileContents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you keep assigning the same array pointer `buff` to each element of the pointer array `fileContents`.

Unless you wish to pre-allocate all strings inside `fileContents` to max size of 255, you need to make copies of the `buf` before making an assignment:

```
while( fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*) fp) ) {
    // copy the file into the array & get the number of strings
    size_t len = strlen(buff);
    char *copy = malloc(len+1);
    strcpy(copy, buf);
    fileContents[stringsInFile] = copy;
    stringsInFile++;
}
```

Since this code uses dynamic allocation, you need to `free` the allocated memory after you are done with it:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != stringsInFile ; i++) {
    free(fileContents[i]);
}
```

Finally, your allocation of `fileContents` to the number of bytes in the file is very conservative: you know you wouldn't go over the limit, but the amount of waste may be too large.

Comment: Ok, so this snippet changes the code from making each element in the array a pointer to whatever was last in buff to making each element the current contents of buff?
Can you explain how I might waste space by the fileContents allocation?
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @vulcao Let's say the file has an average of 20 chars per line. Then a file of 1000 lines would be 20000-char long. You allocate an array of 20,000 pointers, while 1000 would be sufficient.